# Dell Optiplex GX520 Blank when turned on

Tags: windows-xp, boot, memory

I have a problem with my Dell Optiplex GX520 PC. Everytime i turned on the PC, its always show nothing, and the power light are Orange (which means still booting), i waited for 1 hour, it turned green (Ready), but it shows nothing.

So i check the RAM (With opening PC Case), its 1GB. So i Updated the RAM to 2GB, but still doesn't work. I try 5 times, its turned on and booted, and successfully loaded Windows.

But, after i update the RAM, the next day i turned it on, its shows nothing again when the power lights are Green (Ready). I do these step:

- Cleaning the PC from dust (Processor, RAM, Motherboard, DVD), still make no effects
- Change their slot, success, but the next day its Blank again
- Checking for Virus and error Registry (Using SMADAV, and its trusted app, so its not a Rogue Software)
- Using new RAM, still make no effects

So, whats wrong with my Computer? are Optiplex GX520 are old PC's, or there's something like Outdated BIOS or OS (I using Windows XP SP3)?

Comment: Have you tried checking the Ram for errors? are there any beeps?

Comment: How can you be so sure it is a memory issue? You have said nothing about the monitor. Those go bad too. Is the monitor turned on or have power? Are the connections to the monitor seated properly? Have you tried a different monitor to verify yours is working?

Comment: No Memory Beeps, i tried another monitor, good connections to the Monitor, no pins were broken, and the Monitors are turned on, but still had same things

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem.
I have tried Rams processors.
It's either a processor circuit failure or dead mother board.
Anyway I'm too lazy to get the schematics to check it professionally.
Keep pressing the power button turn on and off; you may get lucky to run it again take what you want shut it back and deliver to the nearest rubbish box.
Sorry to say so.